# Hibernate default Locking strategy

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate by default applies locking for applicable hibernate operations.

What will be the default Locking strategy which will be used by Hibernate if not  explicit Locking strategy is specified?

Comment: What do you mean by locking?

Comment: If I load an entity using session.load(Employee.class, 101) [Without specifying  LockOptions ] , will hibernate uses any default LockOptions in this case?